# How to get into root user in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, root

I'm new to Linux and using Ubuntu.
I'm trying to add a new user.
When I use this command "useradd indra", it shows an error message saying that

```
igeek01@igeek01-Lenovo-G585:~$ useradd indra
useradd: Permission denied.
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
igeek01@igeek01-Lenovo-G585:~$ ^C
igeek01@igeek01-Lenovo-G585:~$
```

What should I do to get root access and how to add a new user?

Comment: Welcome to the excellent world of Linux!... Follow this page to get answer to your question https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Answer (score 0):

You don't, there's no root user set up by default.

- when you set up the system, the first user you create has admin rights. This user (or any user in the wheel group) can do anything root can do as sudo. This is safer since you drop back to being a regular user as soon as you're done using a command that needs root.

  Prefacing any command you want to run as root with sudo, and supplying the user's password should do the trick, as long as you're logged in as the original user you created.

So, `sudo useradd indra` would work

- You can use `sudo su` to switch to the root user from your original user. but sudo is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has the root user disabled as a security measure.

Use `sudo` as a way to issue commands only available to root, for example:

```
sudo useradd indra
```

Will ask for your password and if it is correct it will issue the command `useradd indra`as `root`.